# I can't pass data in sailsjs to ejs

Tags: javascript, orm, count, sails.js

i'm trying SailsJs but at the moment to pass the Model.count() value from a table with 4 records, in the ejs view returns "undefined"

// SAILS CODE

```
module.exports = {
create:function(req,res){
    CountOfUsers=User.count().exec(function (error, found){console.log('There are ' + found + ' users');});
    return res.view('privacy', {
        userCount: CountOfUsers
    });
}};
```

// EJS CODE

```
HELLO WORLD! <%= userCount %>
```

// THE RESULT

```
HELLO WORLD! undefined
```

// COMMAND LINE CONSOLE.LOG

```
There are 4 users
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to write `res.locals.userCount = CountOfUsers;` and then later just `res.view();`

Answer (score 1):

The right sintax is:

```
module.exports = {
  create:function(req,res) {
    User.count().exec(function (error, found){
      console.log('There are ' + found + ' users');

      return res.view('privacy', {
          userCount: found
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: if i want pass two or three vars? cause the view function is within the count function callback...

Comment: node.js and javascript works like this, you'll just call res.view after going to the data base take the data so it is inside the callback

Comment: right, but if i want pass 3 or 4 diferent vars like: "title of the page" "users array" "weather in colombia"... how sails allow make this? the same callback of users array can't access to the weather in colombia data...